# Jackson @JsonAlias not deserializing xml

Tags: jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I've got the following

```
@JsonAlias({"TRADE_ID","TradeId"})
private String tradeId;
```

I'm using Jackson 2.9.5, and yet when I try to deserialize

```
 <TRADE_ID>10000001</TRADE_ID>
```

It comes back NULL, as though it didn't find `TRADE_ID`. Previously when I was just using `@JsonProperty("TRADE_ID")`, it worked just fine. So I'm wondering, does `@JsonAlias` not work on XML? Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @SpasojePetronijević I want it to deserialize "TradeId" or "TRADE_ID", and I was it to serialize to "tradeId". It isn't a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out that since I'm doing testing with cucumber, I have cucumber libraries on my path. And when I auto imported JsonAlias, Cucumber JVM 4 actually has a set of Jackson libraries in it (very unhelpfully). And so it imported the wrong version of JsonAlias.

## checkYourImports